# Rails initializer to be more clean

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails

I need a little bit of refactor my initialize method because I think it will make initializer more flexible and readable.

```
class LogAdminData
  DEFAULT_EXCLUDED_PARAMS = %w[
    encrypted_password
    reset_password_token
    reset_password_sent_at
  ].freeze

  def initialize(admin_obj:, action_type:, old_data:, new_data:, excluded_params: %w[])
    excluded_params += DEFAULT_EXCLUDED_PARAMS
    @old_data = old_data.reject { |k, _v| excluded_params.include? k }
    @new_data = new_data.reject { |k, _v| excluded_params.include? k }
    @action_type = action_type
    @admin_email = admin_obj.email
    @admin_role = admin_obj.role
  end

  def call
    AdminPanelLog.create(
      admin_email: admin_email,
      admin_role: admin_role,
      action_type: action_type,
      new_data: new_data,
      old_data: old_data,
    )
  end
```

Maybe something like

```
  def cleanup_data(data)
    excluded_params += DEFAULT_EXCLUDED_PARAMS
    data.reject { |k, _v| excluded_params.include? k }
  end
```

But how to call it in initializer using `old_data` and `new_data`?

Comment: What does this code do, and how is it used? Is this the entire class? As it is, it looks like some essential parts of the code are missing, and your question makes little sense.

Answer (score 0):

If this is a Rails project (or you use ActiveSupport) you can replace

`@old_data = old_data.reject { |k, _v| excluded_params.include? k }`
with
`@old_data = old_data.except(excluded_params)`